# White bootstrap navbar turning transparent over paragraph

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, rgba

I've been working on a navigation that would gain opacity and minify the logo once scrolled past the header -- all well, except for when the navbar overlays a paragraph on a white background, it turns transparent & creates a visual mess. I'm guessing it might be a problem with using rgba? I want to keep opacity, would be grateful on any suggestions how to do so.

Demo here:
http://mockturtlesoup.github.io/Hi-Will/#

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that showcases the problem? If you need placeholder images, I always use [Placehold.it](http://placehold.it/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap. There is no fixed value for this property but you can use higher value to stack element on the top of other elements. Following css will also works.

```
#header {
 z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not transparency problem. It is layering problem. Add this to your css file:

```
#header {
     z-index: 90;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually reason was div and tags overlapping the header you added the z-index property in the **#myNav.affix** there should add  **postion:relative** property then remove the **z-index** and **postion:relative** form the <p> tag  and bootsrap classes also  like col-md-5, because these classes having **postion-realtive** for your reqiurement these are not needed so remove it .am checked itz works fine hope itz works you too .(Y)Try It
```